# Variable 'global' must be of type 'global', but here h as type 'Global'

Tags: typescript, webpack, google-apps-script

I am using GoogleAppsScript with webpack to bundle.
When I try to import`cheerio-httpcli`, I get an error.
Could you tell me how to fix this error?

### Error:

`ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:102:13
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.

Variable 'global' must be of type 'global', but here has type 'Global'.`

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./dev",
    "outDir": "./src",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
        "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./dev/**/*",
        "./node_modules/@types/*"
  ]
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
const GasPlugin = require('gas-webpack-plugin');
const es3ifyPlugin = require('es3ify-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './dev/index.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/src',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new GasPlugin(),
    new es3ifyPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "searchfrombigcamera",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json 'dev/**/*.ts'",
    "upload": "gapps upload",
    "watch": "watch 'npm run build && npm run upload' dev/",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/google-apps-script": "^0.0.14",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.3",
    "es3ify-webpack-plugin": "^0.0.1",
    "gas-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.1",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.2",
    "watch": "^1.0.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/request": "^2.47.0",
    "cheerio-httpcli": "^0.7.3",
    "jsdom": "^11.10.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you installed some new npm package lately?

Comment: @Tiago Machado added package.json. Please confirm

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code or the libraries that you dependent on probably in that cheerio-httpcli you have

```
declare var global: any;
```

Which for some reason typescript compiler complains about. You need to change that to.

```
declare var global: NodeJS.Global;
```

And your error will go away or you might get another error complaining about that it can find NodeJS for that to go away you need to include in tsconfig.json @types folder in node_modules;

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found out the problem is that GoogleAppsScript uses some functions which JavaScript don't use like request.